NDK at /Users/shahirbinzulfikeraorko/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125 did not have a source.properties file
I am new to react native. I was trying to implement the react native navigation .
this error is popping up

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-screens'.


[CXX1101] NDK at /Users/shahirbinzulfikeraorko/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125 did not have a source.properties file


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-screens'.

[CXX1101] NDK at /Users/shahirbinzulfikeraorko/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125 did not have a source.properties file * Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 3s.

I did everything that was mentioned in the docs. These are the dependencies
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.10.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "formik": "^2.4.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.2",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.7",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.32.0",
    "yup": "^1.4.0"
  },

I also edited the MainActivity.kt file as instructed in the docs.
I also installed NDK from android studio and added the path to the local.properties file inside android folder
This is my APP.jsx
import React from 'react';
import Login from './src/screen/Login';
import Register from './src/screen/Register';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import {View, Text, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;


